# jquery datatable serverside processing select row by database id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use a self-made php framework and jquery datatable with the server-side processing method. I write the script automatic with php in the header, all works good. Now i try to find a way for highlight a specific row by a database index field in the datatable-result, in this case “manid". what is the best way?
Her my javascript:

```
    var oTable;
var giRedraw = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    oTable = $('#dt_sys_man').dataTable({
        /* Column Width */
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bVisible": true,"sWidth": "2%","sClass":"ClickClass" },
            { "sWidth": "98%","sClass":"ClickClass" }
            ],

        /* Serverside Prozessing(Ajax) */
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "index.php?res=dt_sys_man",


        /* Default Settings */               
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "bSortable": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
    });

    /* Row Click */
    $('#dt_sys_man tbody td.ClickClass').live('click',function(){
        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);
        /*
        $("#dt_sys_man tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');        
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        */
        window.location = "index.php?do=sys-man&manid="+aData[0]+"&uid=0";
        });

    /* highlite row */
    $("#dt_sys_man tbody tr").live("click", function(event){
          $("td.row_selected", oTable.fnGetNodes()).removeClass('row_selected');
          $(event.target).parent().find("td").addClass('row_selected');
        });
});
```

html:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="dt_sys_man" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>MANID</th>
        <th>Mandant</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: need to be more specific about what you are exactly trying to highlight and based on what event(s)

Comment: I reload the html by click on a datatable row /* Row Click */. After the reload the script should focus the row i have clicked before. Maybe the problem is the reload of the script, but i need it for sub contend conditions…

Comment: I don't understand why you need to reload page when you are using serverside processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fnRowCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnRowCallback) for this:

```
"aoColumns": [
            { "bVisible": true,"sWidth": "2%","sClass":"ClickClass" },
            { "sWidth": "98%","sClass":"ClickClass" }
            ],
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
               if(aData.manid == 'whatever you're checking for'){
                     $(nRow).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
               }
               return nRow;
}
```

This example checks the manid value and if it matches, applies the line-through class to the

**UPDATE**: now that you've elaborated on your question, I realise that this isn't quite what you're looking for.... However, if you were to pass the last clicked rowid back with aData then you *could* use this approach.

Comment: i think it's exactly what im looking for but the script wont work. do i need a seperator after the }     ?

Comment: Sorry - I made a typo in the code (not very helpful!). Fixed now.

Comment: it doesn’t work ..dataTables_empty... could you post the hole code?

Comment: It's your code, I just added the callback function. Looking at your code, I see you're using window.location on the row click event - is that right? If that is the case then you're doing a page refresh, not just reloading the datatable so I don't think the callback function will work as expected.

Comment: Well personally, I wouldn't be using window.location.  You could reload the table, passing a parameter that indicates that you need to return the selected row 'sub-content'